# Ponto e vírgula vazio não dá erro?

Tags: c#, .net, compilação

Eu estava trabalhando em um projeto e sem querer esbarrei no ponto e vírgula que acabou sendo inserido bem após um `if`. Fiquei intrigado pois o Visual Studio não apontou como erro, e ao tentar compilar o projeto obtive sucesso.

O código ficou assim:

```
if(alguma_coisa)
{
   //Bloco lógico
};
```

Motivado pela curiosidade, pude perceber que também é possível inserir ponto e vírgula no final de laços de repetição como **`while`**, **`for`** e **`foreach`**.

Mostrei a um amigo e ele revelou a possibilidade de inserir o ponto e vírgula várias vezes em sequencia em uma mesma linha da seguinte forma:

```
if(alguma_coisa)
{
   //Bloco lógico
}; ; ; ; ; ;
```

E ainda assim o projeto é compilado sem nenhum problema.

> Não deveria ser gerado um erro de compilação?
>   Por que isso é permitido?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

O ponto e vírgula serve para determinar o final de uma instrução. O que acontece neste caso é que "a instrução" não faz nada.

Fazer isso:

```
if(true)
{
};
```

é a mesma coisa que fazer

```
if(true)
{    
}
; //Final da "instrução" que está vazia
```

Answer (score 18):

Esta é uma sintaxe perfeitamente válida, ainda que inócua. Cada ponto-e-vírgula representa o fim de um *statement*; sem conteúdo algum, o bloco é simplemente ignorado quando ocorre a compilação.

Comment: Mal posso ver seus movimentos

Comment: para quem além de mim precisar - http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/in%C3%B3cua/

Answer (score 14):

Entre o fechamento do `if` que é o `}` e o `;` inseridos é um bloco de código que não faz nada.
Mesma coisa entre um `;` e outro `;`

Answer (score 11):

Acho que a questão já foi bem respondida, mas existe um caso que acho importante mencionar aqui.

Da mesma forma que se pode ter ponto e vírgula sem causar erros de compilação, o seguinte código também não causa erros de compilação

```
{
    //bloco lógico
}
```

Veja que é um bloco entre `{ }` sem nenhuma construção lógica, não é um if, for, while ou método qualquer.

O compilador permite que eu faça isso e ele separa o contexto de variáveis caso elas sejam declaradas, por exemplo

```
{
    var i = 1;
    Console.Write(i); //ok
}
Console.Write(i); //erro de compilação, i não existe no contexto atual
```

Mas então o que isso tem a ver com o `;`? No seu primeiro exemplo você colocou um ponto e vírgula depois de fechar o bloco do `if`, mas imagine que sem querer você tivesse feito isso

```
if(alguma_coisa);
{
   //Bloco lógico
}
```

Não iria ocorrer nenhum erro de compilação, o que aconteceria durante a execução é que este `Bloco lógico` sempre seria executado, independente do `if`, e acho que esse é um dos problemas mais comuns que podem acontecer com um ponto e vírgula adicionado por engano.

Um outro caso interessante também é o de um for

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++);
{
    Console.Write(i);
}
```

Então você veria no console apenas um valor, o 10, que nunca deveria aparecer.

Mas este erro é menos comum já que geralmente se declara a variável direto no for, e neste caso ocorreria um erro de compilação

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++);
{
    Console.Write(i); //erro de compilação, i não existe no contexto atual
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Na época da pergunta entendi a respostas como certas e votei nelas. Mas elas estão falando da consequência e não da causa.

É verdade que parece que inteligentemente o compilador elimina o `;` que não tem utilidade prática, é verdade que esse caractere costuma ser usado como terminador de *statement*. Tudo o que está respondido está certo e funciona, mas faltou falar porque funciona.

Mas nesse caso o que se tem é um *empty statement*. [Isso na especificação da linguagem](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). E [há *warning* quando ele pode ser tido usado sem intenção](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/9x19t380(v=vs.90)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

O exemplo da resposta do LINQ mostra que o que parece terminador na verdade é só um *empty statement* na mesma linha. Então

```
if(true)
{
};
```

é realmente o mesmo que

```
if(true)
{    
}
;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Semicolon.cs).

Portanto ele não é um terminador para o bloco do `if`, ele é outro *statement* completamente diferente e que faz nada.

Comment: Isso tem alguma perda de performance por menor que seja?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Em PHP sempre tem porque é uma linguagem interpretada, porque tem um caractere a mais para interpretar, mas é uma perda muito pequena e ocore apenas uma vez, mesmo que isso esteja em um laço, afinal é só no processo de interpretação e não de execução. Note que essa "perda" é a mesma de dar um ENTER, um espaço, nada que realmente deva se preocupar.

Comment: Ao meu ver a resposta esta boa, mas creio que poderia ficar melhor falando diretamente do analisador léxico. Não apenas implicitamente em "outro statement completamente diferente".

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert não entendi o que quer dizer com isso.

Comment: Independente da linguagem ser interpretada ou compilada, quem define o *statement* é o analisador léxico, o analisador quem define onde inicia/termina. Desta forma creio que estaria mais completo explicando este fato.

Answer (score 9):

O compilador do C# - Roslyn, na versão mais atual - possui "inteligência" para suprir essas situações.

- Multiplos ponto-e-vírgula: `return; ; ;` => `return;`
- Concatenação de strings: `string a = "b" + "c";` => `var a = string.Concat("b", "c");`
- Virgula excedente: `var a = new int[] {1,2,3,};` => `var a = new[]{1,2,3};`

Inclusive eliminação de variáveis declaradas e não utilizadas:

`var a = UmMetodoQualquer();` => `UmMetodoQualquer();`

Por isso que há erros de compilação nesses casos, pois o compilador do C# analisa e faz essas pequenas "correções".