# O que são estruturas de Registro no C#?

Tags: c#, terminologia, record-types

Fiquei sabendo que na atualização 9 do C#, veio algo chamado como "Records", ou Estruturas de Registro, que é algo mais ou menos assim:

```
public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
```

Ou pode ser escrito desta maneira:

```
public record Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; } = default!;
    public string LastName { get; init; } = default!;
}; // -< note o ponto e vírgula no final
```

Também notei essa nova keyword `init` mas também não sei o que ela faz aqui.

O que são registros e para que servem? Quando vamos utilizar eles no nosso dia-a-dia?

Comment: Sobre o `;`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102682/18246

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na versão 9 vieram as classes de registro (`record class`) que por padrão não precisa dizer que é classe. Na 10 veio o `record struct`, ou estrutura de registro que faz o mesmo para `struct`, ainda que com pequenas diferenças.

Eu já dei uma introdução ao assunto em [Quando usar record ou class no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/481890/101), mas não falei como ela se comporta em detalhes. Parte da resposta está lá.

O `;` é, como sempre foi, completamente opcional e sem sentido de usar neste ponto, inclusive só pode usar porque na verdade, ao contrário do que parece, o código que está escrevendo é este:

```
public record Person {
    public string FirstName { get; init; } = default!;
    public string LastName { get; init; } = default!;
}
;
```

A exclamação é outra questão e não obrigatória (depende da intenção).

## `init`

Vou começar falando do `init` que é um mecanismo interessante para facilitar a imutabilidade e não precisar tanto de [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) (que pode dar um tiro no seu pé se abusar).

Ele diz que aquela propriedade pode ser inicializada **na criação** do objeto, mas não pode ser modificada depois, ao contrário do `set` que permite modificar quando quiser. Obviamente que a propriedade se torna imutável se escrita exatamente desta forma.

E tem a forma de declarar o registro que mantém a imutabilidade sem construtor e sem `init`, é o *primary constructor*:

```
record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
```

Nenhuma dessas formas é exclusiva do `record`, pelo menos não na versão 10.

Na 11 tem o modificador `required` que obriga a inicialização da propriedade na criação do objeto.

## `record` por baixo dos panos

Uma das grandes vantagens de usar isso sobre a classe é que ele cria automaticamente alguns métodos para você. E isso é diferente de herdar de outra classe. É um método próprio escrito pelo compilador.

Isso facilita muito e evita muito erro. A maioria das classes, e principalmente estruturas, que as pessoas criam em C# estão erradas, mas como funciona as pessoas aceitam. Em geral faltam alguns métodos para o objeto funcionar 100% do jeito que deveria. Por sorte o erro ocorre mais em `struct`, que as pessoas quase não criam (deveriam, o não uso delas é outro "erro").

Assim evita-se que a pessoa crie [`ToString()` que faça mais coisa do que deveria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101) como muito ocorre muito, evita-se um `GetHashCode()` fraco, evita-se um erro no `Equals()`, eventualmente cria-se um `Deconstruct()` tão útil para pegar os valores dos membros do objeto, e ainda tem um método que será usado com o novo comando `with` para copiar um objeto imutável fazendo uma nova inicialização no novo objeto.

Vou colocar aqui o código gerado quando programa esse `record`:

```
internal class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly string <FirstName>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly string <LastName>k__BackingField;

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Nullable(1)]
    protected virtual Type EqualityContract
    {
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return typeof(Person);
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <FirstName>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        init
        {
            <FirstName>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <LastName>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        init
        {
            <LastName>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    public Person(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        <FirstName>k__BackingField = FirstName;
        <LastName>k__BackingField = LastName;
        base..ctor();
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append("Person");
        stringBuilder.Append(" { ");
        if (PrintMembers(stringBuilder))
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(" ");
        }
        stringBuilder.Append("}");
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
    protected virtual bool PrintMembers(StringBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Append("FirstName");
        builder.Append(" = ");
        builder.Append((object)FirstName);
        builder.Append(", ");
        builder.Append("LastName");
        builder.Append(" = ");
        builder.Append((object)LastName);
        return true;
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    public static bool operator !=(Person left, Person right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    public static bool operator ==(Person left, Person right)
    {
        return (object)left == right || ((object)left != null && left.Equals(right));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (EqualityComparer<Type>.Default.GetHashCode(EqualityContract) * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(<FirstName>k__BackingField)) * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(<LastName>k__BackingField);
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Person);
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(2)]
    public virtual bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        return (object)this == other || ((object)other != null && EqualityContract == other.EqualityContract && EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(<FirstName>k__BackingField, other.<FirstName>k__BackingField) && EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(<LastName>k__BackingField, other.<LastName>k__BackingField));
    }

    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
    public virtual Person <Clone>$()
    {
        return new Person(this);
    }

    protected Person([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Nullable(1)] Person original)
    {
        <FirstName>k__BackingField = original.<FirstName>k__BackingField;
        <LastName>k__BackingField = original.<LastName>k__BackingField;
    }

    public void Deconstruct(out string FirstName, out string LastName)
    {
        FirstName = this.FirstName;
        LastName = this.LastName;
    }
}
```

Pra falar a verdade não sou fã de algumas decisões tomadas, por exemplo o `ToString()` não é tão simples e eficiente quanto poderia. E não gosto que não cria o `Deconstruct()` em todos os casos.

Mas vê-se que não é diferente de uma classe, só é uma forma mais simples de fazer. O mesmo vale para a estrutura.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#deconstructor-behavior-in-derived-records?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/RecordLowered.cs).

Comment: Sobre o init, `public string LastName {get;} => "Meu nome"` ainda serve como a mesma coisa para um `public string LastName {get; init;} => "Meu nome"`, pois ambos inicializam a propriedade. Qual a diferença?

Comment: O segundo permite inicializar na criação do objeto e passar por cima do valor padrão que você colocou.

Comment: @CypherPotato Sobre o `init`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499910/18246