# Como implementar IClonable em um tipo no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, clone

Quando queremos que um objeto seja facilmente copiado podemos implementar a interface [`IClonable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e o método `Clone()`. Esta cópia pode ser feita com profundidade ou não, já que a documentação diz que não tem uma forma certa.

Então como saber qual é a forma certa? Quais critérios devem ser adotados para decidir como implementar corretamente para cada tipo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A interface `IClonable` acabou sendo uma má ideia e deve ser evitada. Justamente porque não se sabe como será feito, e para algo universal deveria ter uma forma específica. O que torna inviável porque nem todos os objetos podem ser feitos da mesma forma. Em alguns casos a cópia profunda pode ser problemática, e a cópia rasa pode dar resultados indesejáveis, para dizer o mínimo. Quem vai chamar o `Clone()` precisa saber como foi implementada.

[Considere essa interface obsoleta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/should-we-obsolete-icloneable-the-slar-on-system-icloneable) e não a use.

O que fazer então?

Crie um método `Copy()` para evitar confusão e estabeleça um critério e o chame sabendo desse critério. Como ele não faz parte de algo usado universalmente não tem problema, só vai chamar onde sabe qual é o critério usado para copiar o objeto. O ideal é adotar um critério único, por exemplo que seja *shallow copy*.

Um [`record`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/539114/101) faz uma cópia rasa quando usa o [`with`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Todo objeto tem o método [`MemberWiseClone()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que copia o objeto de forma rasa sempre.

Você pode até criar uma interface sua para usar universalmente, mas tenha certeza que está documentado "proibindo" o uso de critério que não seja a cópia rasa, e avise que isso pode trazer problemas em alguns objetos, portanto eles não deveriam usar isso.

O mais comum é fazer esse tipo de cópia. Não tem problemas quando são objetos por valor ou imutáveis por referência. Os mutáveis por referência precisa cuidado porque alterando de um objeto altera do outro copiado também, mesmo sem mexer nele, nem sempre é o que deseja.

Por outro lado, pode ser o que deseja e precisa colocar tudo e torne completamente independente.

Algumas pessoas adotam o critério de *deep copy* apenas com um construtor de cópia, ou seja, um construtor que recebe um objeto do mesmo tipo para inicializar o novo objeto. Obviamente ele não participa de herança. Outra possibilidade é ter um método `DeepCopy()` para este fim.

Pode ser mais complicado porque pode ter campos que devem ser copiados de um jeito e outros copiados de outro. Aí não tem como você classificar o método como sendo raso ou profundo, tem que especificar cada campo, que é um [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101). Engenharia de software pode ser bem mais complicada do que parece, por isso em muitos casos fazer o simples, até mesmo o menos robusto, é mais fácil.

Copiar objetos é algo muito mais complicado do que as pessoas imaginam. E muitas cópias ocorrem sem ser facilmente perceptível.

Comment: E qual o jeito certo de copiar um objeto?

Comment: Não existe exatamente o jeito certo, cada objeto pode exigir uma forma diferente, mas todas vão sendo transportar um valor por vez de um objeto para o outro. Em raríssimos casos uma cópia bruta do objeto em baixo nível é interessante.